# Is there a way to fully ignoreRepaint in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, awt, paint, bufferstrategy

I'm using setIgnoreRepaint(true) on my JFrame with Active Rendering and a BufferStrategy. When I disable the portion of code that is calling contentPane.repaintAll() from the EDT withing my game loop, nothing get's drawn anymore which is expected, except a JPanel that I animate through setLocation that still receives paint calls and flickers with the BufferStrategy, that's what I don't understand, how can it still be drawn on the screen if the JFrame itself ignores repaint? Should I write a custom RepaintManager ?

Comment: So much of that makes no sense, *"except a JPanel that I animate through setLocation that still receives paint calls and flickers with the BufferStrategy"* - why are you mixing swing components with a `BufferStrategy`?  The whole point of a `BufferStrategy` is take control over the painting process manually, Swing components have a dedicated (and complex) painting process which makes then incompatible with `BufferStrategy` workflows

Comment: From what (little) I understand of `setIgnoreRepaint`, this only effects paint messages received from the OS, which might benefit "full screen exclusive mode" workflows

Comment: *"Should I write a custom RepaintManager ?"* if you're using `BufferStrategy` (correctly) there should be no point, as the `BufferStrategy` is not controlled by Swing's paint workflow, it's independent of it, which is kind of the point

Comment: Alright I see thank you @MadProgrammer, what i'm trying to do is render all my swing components inside of my game loop that just does update(), render() and wait for optimal frame time ( to clamp to 60 fps), if buffer strategy is not the way to go, how can i manually handle the drawing of all the components in a buffer before displaying it to the screen?

Comment: Don't mix Swing (passive rendering) with `BufferStrategy` (active rendering), they aren't compatible.  Instead, if you want to use Swing components, seperate the views and only display one or the other (there's some tricks you can use to fake it).  If you need something more complex, ie you need to continue rendering the output, but want to display "controls" over the top, then you need to create that yourself (these would be entities of some type which could be passed mouse/keyboard states and could then perform operations as required)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh okay I think I get it, i should paint every texture of the game with passive rendering (and probably AWT ?) and use swing only for controls and display it normally with passive rendering on top of everything ?

Comment: Just remember, Swing and `BufferStrategy` aren't compatible, you can't display both at the same, you'll have all sorts of issues if you try